# Maximize and NMaximize don't work for my function

Tags: mathematical-optimization, piecewise

I defined the following function:

> d1[x_] := Min[Abs[FractionalPart[x]], 1 - Abs[FractionalPart[x]]]

and tried to evaluate the following function:

> Maximize[{Min[d1[15*x],d1[12*x],d1[18*x]],Abs[x-0.25]<=0.25},x]

Similar evaluation resulted in correct answer when 12, 15, and 18 were replaced with other integer values, but in this case (12, 15 and 18), the evaluation is not correct, as the plot shows that the global maximum of min function is 0.4 (instead of 0.2222). How could I avoid this problem? Is there any better way to get the global maximum of this sort of piece-wise linear function?
[image]

Comment: What happens if you replace the `0.25` with `1/4`?

Comment: V10.1 gives the correct results. {0.39999, {x -> 0.0333325}}

Comment: @J. M. Replacing with 1/4 gave the same result.

Comment: @Algohi the version of my Mathematica is 9.0, so the implemented algorithm must be quite different. How do you think I can use the newer version of Maximize function?

Comment: Try changing the constraint to `0 <= x <= 1/2` in addition to the `1/4` replacement.

Comment: I don't know why, but whenever I use fraction instead of floating number for this inequality part, my Mathematica crushes. But by using 0<=x<=0.5 instead, I got a correct value. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't believe that crash is supposed to happen; please mention your version number and OS.

Comment: @J. M. The version number is 9.0, and OS is Windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: Something must have been mucked up in the symbolics, then; you see, when inexact numbers are present in the objective or the constraints, `Maximize[]` switches to the use of `NMaximize[]` which runs the risk of being trapped in local optima unless given appropriate option settings.

Comment: I see... I'll be careful about exactness of numbers from the next time I will use this function.